# Unexpected behavior when filtering arrays with tuples

Tags: python

I have a 5x5 grid of Light objects. When one is switched, the four adjacent lights also switch.

However, lights don't exist beyond the first or fifth row or column and thus do not switch.

Here is my logic:

```py
def toggle_adjacent_lights(self, light):
    adjacent_lights_unfiltered = [
        (light.x + 1, light.y), 
        (light.x - 1, light.y), 
        (light.x, light.y - 1),
        (light.x, light.y + 1)
    ]

    adjacent_lights = []
    for i in adjacent_lights_unfiltered:
        if 4 < i[0] >= 0 or i[1] >= 0:
            adjacent_lights.append(i)

    for a, b in adjacent_lights:
        self.board[a][b].toggle()
```

I, however, am still getting values in the `adjacent_lights` list that are either negative or greater than 4.

Where am I going wrong? This is the second implementation attempt -- the first used the `.remove()` method and still yielded same results.

Comment: `4 < i[0] >= 0` is redundant for `4 < i[0]`

Comment: `4 < i[0]` means that the value is greater than 4. Why shouldn't you get them?

Comment: I suspect you meant `if 0 <= i[0]  < 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want elements where the row and column are between 0 and 3, your `if` statement should be:

```
if 0 <= i[0] < 4 and 0 <= i[1] < 4:
```

Your statement is matching when `x` is at least 4 (not less than 4) or `y` is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more compact by using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Assuming that by "adjacent" you mean 4-connected neighbourhood, the snippet above should get the job done:

```py
import itertools

def toggle_adjacent_lights(self, light):
    for dx, dy in itertools.product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=2):
        x, y = light.x + dx, light.y + dy
        if 0 <= x <= 4 and 0 <= y <= 4 and dx*dy == 0 and not dx == dy == 0:
            self.board[x][y].toggle()
```

If you want to toggle the lights in the 8-connected neighbourhood, simply remove `dx*dy == 0` from the conditional:

```py
        if 0 <= x <= 4 and 0 <= y <= 4 and not dx == dy == 0:
            self.board[x][y].toggle()
```